# How to return hstores correctly from PostgreSQL using Sequel

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have a PostgreSQL table with an array of hstores, `hstore[]`, and I'm using Sequel, but it doesn't work.

It's returning the raw string representation of the `hstore` array, so when I call

```
DB[:invoices][id: 1337].line_items
```

I get:

```
"{\"\\\"amount\\\"=>\\\"795\\\", \\\"description\\\"=>\\\"Box\\\"\",\"\\\"amount\\\"=>\\\"200\\\", \\\"description\\\"=>\\\"Shipping\\\"\"}"
```

instead of:

```
[{'amount' => 795, 'description' => 'Box' ...}]
```

I'm connecting to the database using:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL')).tap do |db|
  Sequel.extension :pg_hstore_ops
  db.extension :pg_hstore
  db.extension :pg_array
  db.extension :pg_json
  db.extension :pg_streaming
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Sequel extensions are order-dependent. This only works if `db.extension :pg_hstore` is called *after* `db.extension :pg_array`.

So the config block for the DB should be:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL')).tap do |db|
  Sequel.extension :pg_hstore_ops
  db.extension :pg_array
  db.extension :pg_hstore # This is now after :pg_array!
  db.extension :pg_json
  db.extension :pg_streaming
end
```

Comment: Sorry about that, most Sequel pg_* extensions document this requirement.  pg_hstore is one of the two that didn't.  I just fixed that: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/commit/60795802a37c680c76d3aff33aa118bd3994aa0e

Comment: No problem. Thanks Jeremy!